# th:block and th:remove="tag" adding undesired spaces

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to generate plain text (without surrounding tag) but for some reason I am getting undesired "white" characters. If I try

```
<th:span th:text="myText" th:remove="tag">Placeholder text</th:span>
```

or

```
<th:block th:text="myText">Placeholder text</th:block>
```

I get:

```
"
                                            myText

                                    "
```

I am not sure if this might affect but one line after I make a recursive call:

```
<div th:with="nodelist = ${node.children}" th:include="this::fragmentid" th:remove="tag"></div>
```

What might be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to use [thymeleaf-extras](https://github.com/connect-group/thymeleaf-extras) for that.